# Adding className to specific array items in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, conditional-statements

I'm trying to add a **className** to option elements in a select element using a conditional **if** statement so the first half of the array has one class name and the second half has a different class name. This conditional statement is in a **for** loop because I need to set the disabled value for every option element to 'true' on page load.

The loop runs, and the conditional runs, but the conditional sets the class names for every option in the array to the same class name. I am having a hard time finding a solution to this online so it's time I pose my own question.

Here's an example of my code. (Note: the array length is 6)

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i].disabled = true;

  if (array[i] <= 2) {
    array[i].className = 'classOne';
  } else {
    array[i].className = 'classTwo';
  }
}
```

So, yeah, every option element gets the **className** of "classTwo". I'm having a rough go of it over here.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to change:

`if (array[i] <= 2) {`

to

`if (i <= 2) {`

Since you're array items are objects and not numbers.